# Including a class library with a WSPBuilder deployment in WSS

Tags: wss-3.0, visual-studio, wspbuilder

I am working with WSS 3.0, Visual Studio 2008, and WSPBuilder 0.9.9. I have a custom class library (WebParts.dll) of base classes that I use with several SharePoint solutions. I currently deploy WebParts.dll to the GAC, and add it as a reference in each solution.  My current arrangement works fine, but I have to manually deploy the DLL to the GAC on each web server when it changes.

I would prefer to either (a) wrap WebParts.dll in a WSPBuilder or VseWSS solution that can be deployed just like any other solution, or (b) include WebParts.dll in the 80/bin folder in each solution.

Which would be the preferred method to deploy my dll, and can someone point me to step-by-step instructions online?  I found this blog post describing some of part b, but I think I am missing a step:

http://blog.vanmeeuwen-online.nl/2010/05/deployment-of-class-library-with.html

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your DLL is placed in the ***bin\debug*** or ***bin\release*** folders of your project (*e.g.* "Copy Local" equal to true for your DLL Reference), the DLL will automatically be included in your WSP and deploy according to the **DeploymentTarget** of your local **WSPBuilder.exe.config** file.

If you are sharing the same DLL across multiple projects, it might make more sense for you to package the shared DLL in it's own feature/deployment package and utilize feature [activation dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543162%28v=office.12%29.aspx) within your other projects to ensure the DLL has been deployed.

You may need to upgrade to a more recent version of WSPBuilder. I believe [1.0.5](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/releases/view/16820) is the first release to support local config support.

- [Using Local Config Files with WSPBuilder](http://www.michaelbowersox.com/2009/04/22/using-local-config-files-with-wspbuilder/)
- [WSPBuilder (with local config file support)](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/releases/view/16820)
- [WSPBuilder Manual](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/33013#166101)
- [How to: Set the Copy Local Property of a Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

### **Hypothetical Setup**

- My Web Parts (VS Solution)

  - WebParts (VS Project) - This contains your base DLL (WebParts.DLL) that you want to utilize within your other projects
  - MyWebPart1 (VS Project) - This project is one of your web parts. Add a project reference to the **WebParts** project and **do not** copy the WebParts.DLL locally.
  - MyWebPart2 (VS Project) - This project is one of your web parts. Add a project reference to the **WebParts** project and **do not** copy the WebParts.DLL locally.

When you build the VS projects WebPart1 or WebPart2, the reference will resolve in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks! Your second paragraph is my option (a), which I think is the better way to go. Could you provide a link to a walkthrough on wrapping a DLL within a WSPBuilder solution? I feel I am close to a solution, but need that aha moment to make it work.

Comment: @cigardoug If your goal is to deploy a single DLL in it's own WSP you could do the following:

1. Create an empty WSPBuilder Project
2. In the root of your project, create a folder called **GAC**
3. Place your DLL in the **GAC** folder
4. Package and Deploy your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, and I imagine that will work. The only problem is, I have to make two solutions, one that generates WebParts.dll and one that wraps WebParts.dll in a solution, WebParts.wsp.

I guess what I was looking for is a way to create ONE WSPBuilder solution, add the classes to the solution like I would add WebParts or EventHandlers to a solution, then deploy the solution. Is this feasible, or am I just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: @cigardoug You can do that in one solution. Create a new empty WSPBuilder project called WebParts. Add your classes. Compile --> Package --> Deploy.

Comment: Which is exactly what I have been trying for two days, without success. I am certain I am missing something so obvious, I will slap myself when I figure it out. OK, so here is the question: The example you gave, how do other solutions refer to it? Does it generate a DLL and add it to the GAC? Do you make a reference to WebParts from the other solutions? Is there a step-by-step online that I can read through and figure out just what I am missing here?

Comment: @CigarDoug There is an existing answer [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/best-practices-for-creating-a-shared-code-library-for-sharepoint-projects/19606#19606) that seems applicable to your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ciphertxt. I created one project (WebParts) that generates the .dll, and another using WSPBuilder (Libraries) that has the WebParts.dll in the GAC folder. This makes more sense for future expansion, in that I can use WebParts.dll in Web-based apps or wherever else, also I can bundle multiple .dlls in the Libraries solution and deploy them all together. When I have time, I may revisit the other option of just adding the classes to the WSPBuilder solution, but not today.